# find average in remaining days using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

df is a csv file that contains ship_date, order_date and cumulative_ordered. cumulative_ordered is the sum of orders added on every day up until ship_date. There are 30 days prior to every ship_date and those days only counts for one ship_date. after ship_date 2018-07-01, then next ship_date will be 2018-08-01 with same procedure.

My problem is that I can't get days remaining(see last code output below) when I calculate the percentage average of cumulative_ordered on each of those 30 days prior.

I have the following code, that gives me the days_remaining from a csv file with several different ship_date and order_date counting down to each separate ship_date.

```
df['days_remaining'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ship_date']).sub\
(pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])).dt.days
df['difference'] = df['ship_date'] - df['order_date']

df.head()
```

output:

```
ship_date    Order_date   cumulative_ordered   days_remaining    difference

2018-07-01   2018-06-01     7                  30               30 days
2018-07-01   2018-06-02     10                 29               29 days
2018-07-01   2018-06-03     15                 28               28 days
2018-07-01   2018-06-04     30                 28               27 days
2018-07-01   2018-06-05     41                 28               26 days
```

I then try to find total ordered on each day prior to ship_date

```
m = df.groupby("difference").mean()
m.head()
```

which gives me this output:

```
             cumulative ordered    days_remaining
difference                            
      0 days    352.458124             0.0
      1 days    291.234747             1.0
      2 days    244.122137             2.0
      3 days    201.178765             3.0
      4 days    190.153641             4.0
```

I'm running into an issue when I try to find an average of cumulative ordered on each day in terms of percentage filled from cumulative_ordered output on 0 days above, by running this code:

```
   v = m/m[m.index.days == 0].iloc[0]
   v.head()

          cumulative_ordered      days_remaining
difference                           
0 days        1.000000              NaN
1 days        0.891324              inf
2 days        0.812534              inf
3 days        0.752339              inf
4 days        0.673745              inf
```

days_remaining changes to NaN and inf.. How can I keep it so it still gives me integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NaN` and `inf` result from dividing by `0.0`.

It seems that you are trying to apply the operation only to the `cumulative_ordered` column, so you should just run this for your last block of code:

```
m['cumulative_ordered'] = m['cumulative_ordered'] / m['cumulative_ordered'][m['cumulative_ordered'].index.days == 0]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is not working because I need the days_remaining column to be able to merge with another csv file and from there make a forecast based on cumulative_ordered average.

Comment: What is the desired output for `days_remaining`?

Comment: no change, just for it to remain the same as above.. counting down the days..
0,1,2 etc

Comment: Yeah, so I thought if you run the line I suggested, `days_remaining` would remain unchanged. And if you print  `m.head()`, `cumulative_ordered` would be the only column modified (if you want `days_remaining` to be integers instead of floats, that is another issue).